# Why Levenshtein distance from "abcd" to "badc" is 3?

Tags: levenshtein-distance

Starting from "abcd", I want to go to "badc" :

- I remove "a" -> "bcd";
- I insert "a" at the right position -> "bacd";
- I remove "c" -> "bad";
- I insert "c" at the right position -> "badc".

It's 4 operations. I can't find out a shorter way to do it. However, Levenshtein distance returns me a cost of 3. Why is that?

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go from `abcd` to `badc` in 3 operations. Remember you can do insertions, deletions and substitutions:

1. Remove `a` -> `bcd`.
2. Substitute `c` with `a` -> `bad`.
3. Add `c` at the end -> `badc`.

More generally, an insert + remove pair of operations can be coalesced into a substitution if the insertion and the removal are adjacent.

Comment: Pfiouu thank you, I'm stuck with this for an hour. Sometimes the simplest problems are the most difficult to solve, especially when the answer is just in front of you...